# opencpu: how to pass a script along with the data frame, and get back results

Tags: opencpu

I am trying to find a way to remotely execute R code by passing input data (typically a data frame) and a script to opencpu (both data and script are generated on the client). The result of the remote execution would be the values of the specified variables (scalars or data frames), plus all graphics generated by the script.

Is it possible to do using opencpu? I've been playing with its API for a while, but have not found a way to do it so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you have to pass your data frame as a json in your parameter.

With ocpu.call, you can get multiple elements from one call, including graphs.